# Rename sequential files (replicates) in folder with a dash before pattern? [Python]

Tags: python, r, file-rename

**1) Summarize the problem:** I have hundreds of files that I need to rename, but they come in replicated sets of 5 (duplicate samples to average across- so cannot simply take one from each since they have different data). The file names start with "f" and then some number (1, 2, 4, 5, 7, and 8) then a treatment condition.

- *But* the treatment conditions differ *both before and after* the f series label. Example: "f1 con npd1" (with 1-5) and a set "f1 con npd1 wnt5a[nums 1-5]". A set of "f1 **os** npd1[nums 1-5]" with the same variation
- This creates problems for my R function to clean the data because it finds the match - so I want to add something that distinguishes these sets earlier in the matching so my filter is more precise in R.
- I want to add a "_" in *only the sequences with **just npd1 and not npd1 wnt5a***

**2, 3) What I have tried:**

```
from glob import glob
import os
#os.chdir('C:Users/jbla12/Desktop/R Analyses/p65_project/dup files/') 
pre = "_"
[os.rename(f, "{}{}".format(pre, f)) for f in glob("f2 con npd1 wnt5a*")]
```

- which just returned a list none

```
import fnmatch
import shutil
import os
file_pattern = 'f2 con npd1 wnt5a*'
files = os.listdir("C:Users/jbla12/Desktop/R Analyses/p65_project/dup files/")
dest = 'f2 con npd1_wnt5a'
for filename in files:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, file_pattern):
        dest = dest + 'statistics_Intensity_Sum_Ch=3_Img=1.csv'
        os.rename(filename, )
        print(file)
```

- which returned nothing and did not change the files

I have scoured SO and googled for things like "rename files with matching patterns in sequence" but there seems to be a gap here. I know it seems oddly specific, but the replicate files/samples with multiple treatment combinations are the complicating factor.

Answer (score 0):

**I had to recheck the files in the right folder, but this appears to have done the trick:**

```
from glob import glob
import os
#os.chdir('C:Users/jbla12/Desktop/R Analyses/p65_project/dup files/') 
pre = "_"
[os.rename(f, "{}{}".format(pre, f)) for f in glob("f2 con npd1 wnt5a*")]
```

Sorry to not have fully verified!